# finding out if two people hold the same ip address php and sql

Tags: php, mysql

Right, I have done a small amount of coding, but have yet to find out how to do the following.

If two users have the same IP address, to mark it through echo.

I wish to make it so that `if($user222['current_ip'] (has the same as another user)); { //do action`

but I can not find the code any where... does it exsist?

I'd be forever grateful for any help (if you can)

my codes are the following:

```
`$usersearch = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE online = 'Online'");
$user222 = mysql_fetch_array($usersearch);`



<? if ($user222['reg_ip'] == $user222['current_ip']) {
    echo "<font color='green'><b>".$user222['current_ip']."</b></font>";
    } else if ($user222['reg_ip'] != $user222['current_ip']) {
    echo "<font color='orange'><b>".$user222['current_ip']."</b></font>"; } else     //add new code here ?>
```

EDIT::: I am wanting to find out if two users are registered with the same IP address through SQL. If there is then to echo the reason.

Comment: You know that in general users, possibly many users, will have the same IP?  For example, most AOL users (yes they still exist) come from a very small set of proxy server IP's.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very vague, however the client IP address can be obtained in PHP like this:

```
$client_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies if you want to figure out if users are different based upon their browsers. One user could use multiple browsers, though.

Comment: well, I am wanting to find out if two users have the same IP address within mysql. and if they do to echo the reason.

Comment: When users first visit the page, it could store a cookie with an id in their browser. In mysql, it could store the id and their ip. Then it could check for records with the same ip but different ids and display the message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

As anttix said, you can use "$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']" to obtain the user IP address. You have to register in the MySQL database all the IP addresses, of course.

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE
    ip = '$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]';
");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $row[ip]) {
        // do something
    }
}
```